# Connect two mosfets with their sources common

Tags: mosfet, ac

I want to create a "digital AC switch". I came across people using two FETs with their sources common. The AC source is 80V.

The load will draw around 300mA.

Is this circuit, the digital AC switch part correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6wtnT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: basically yes, but most likely the common source point is floating.. Are you sure it is grounded? Which kind of ground? **Are you sure the AC source is *not* ground referenced?**

Comment: You might want to look into photomos transistors. The voltages & currents you need should nicely fit some relatively inexpensive part numbers, and you just need a resistor to drive the LED, rather than a gate drive circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawn situation is fine **if your AC source has both sides floating** with respect to "ground":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU5gBU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some situation that do not satisfy this, and which could be therefore **dangerous** or lead to **malfunction**:

- Either side of the AC source is also "ground" or also "Vg"
- The two poles of the AC source have a low-impedance relation to ground or to "Vg", e.g.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYLkmt.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for taking  the time to answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that circuit will work. Indeed, that's the circuit used in protector Li-ion BMS, and in AC/DC Solid State Relays (with MOSFETs).

I assume that the GND note is not referenced to the AC supply in any way.

Comment: The Ground shown in the diagram is not connected to the AC source negative.

Comment: @JoeyB that is not the question. And if they were, then any component between them would be redundant anyway. The question is if the AC is galvanically ground *referenced*?

Comment: @tobalt what do you mean by AC is galvanically ground ref? Do you mean is the AC isolated from the Gate drive ground?

Comment: @JoeyB Yes, isolated would be the opposite  of the former.

Comment: @tobalt the ground of the gate drive is connected to the source, are you saying that the ground of the gate drive signal should be isolated from the common sources? Can you draw how it should look?

Comment: @JoeyB there are many ways how it can and can't look. probably just try: if it is wrong, it can be mildly dangerous so handle with care. If it doesn't work as expected it is probably because there is no galvanic isolation between the AC reference and gate supply reference. The important part in Davide's answer is *really* the last sentence

Comment: @tobalt if I am connecting the ground of the gate drive supply to the common sources then I do not have isolation because the the AC source is connected to the ground of the gate drive supply. Hence I do not have isolation, is this statement correct?